# Any way to automatically generate a UML diagram?

Tags: mysql, uml, relational-database

I have a MySQL DB and I would like to generate its relational diagram. Is there a tool that can connect to the DB and automatically generate it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, DEVART's DBForge for MySQL will do this.

There is a free Express edition, I'm not sure it has this functionality, but have a look at: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/

Comment: I would assume that such a nice feature wouldn't be free or even in the trial lol. Thanks though! If there are any other tools out there please let me know.

Comment: @K-RAN, it's definitely in the trail.

Comment: Oh and I'm working on a mac. Which means that I can't use it :(

Comment: Anyway, here it is a list of features/editions - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/editions.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are a happy owner of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition, you can use its [database tools](http://goo.gl/fTcXjO). IDEA is able to connect to databases and build UML diagrams.