# Import Mysql Workbench UML diagram in ArgoUML

Tags: uml, mysql-workbench, argouml

I have a big database and I need to create an uml diagram.

The only program I find to make this automatically is Mysql Workbench, but I don't like it to work. I usually work with Argouml.

Mysql workbench exports a .mwb, this is a compressed file with an xml file inside. This xml is not compatible to import in Argouml. Argouml only imports .xmi files.

How can I convert mwb to xmi file? or is there any other program to create uml from .sql file or database connection and export in .xmi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using, [DB Designer 4](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/index.php) as it integrates with Mysql Workbench.  I have not personally used this however.  Also, for your consideration, [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838156/any-way-to-automatically-generate-a-uml-diagram).

Finally, assuming ArgoUML can import XSI formatted UML then this script ([mysql2xmi.sh](http://uml.sourceforge.net/developers/mysql2xmi.sh)) might work, from http://uml.sourceforge.net/developers.php

Good luck, I would try and go through XSI formatted UML, most supported and transportable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with ArgoUML, you can reverse engineer from the database using [argouml-db](http://argouml-db.tigris.org/).